# how to vectorise code using numpy in python?

Tags: python, numpy

I need to normalised code using vectorization.
The full code without vectorisation looks like:

```
width = 1024
height = 429

fov = 24.0
origin = (0, 0, -fov / 36.0)

start = numpy.zeros((height, width, 3))
norm = numpy.empty((height, width, 3))

for v in range(height):
  for u in range(width):
    lensqr = 0.0
    for d in range(3): # 3 dimensions
      norm[v, u, d] = start[v, u, d] - origin[d]
      lensqr += norm[v, u, d]**2

    length = numpy.sqrt(lensqr)
    for d in range(3):
      norm[v, u, d] /= length
```

also there need are some certain condition
we need to calculate length using

```
length = numpy.sqrt(numpy.square(direction).sum())
```

where direction = start - origin

Also we need to use axis keyword of sum() for vectorising the length calculation.

Comment: Could you add a description what the code should do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the same as your code in vectorized fashion:

```
import numpy as np

width = 1024
height = 429

fov = 24.0
origin = (0, 0, -fov / 36.0)
origin_tiled = np.tile(origin, (height, width, 1))

start = np.zeros((height, width, 3))
norm = start - origin_tiled

lensqr = np.sum(norm**2, axis=2)
length = np.sqrt(lensqr)
norm = norm / length[ :, :,None]
```

I'm not sure what exactly you mean with the second part of your question, however this should get you started.